# Trigger after_destroy call back when related model destroyed with `update_attributes!`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `User` that has many `Membership`s (sample code at bottom).

In a part of my app I update the user and its related memberships with `@user.update_attributes!(membership_params)`. When this is called in a method that creates one or more memberships, the membership(s) are created and `after_create` callbacks on the `Membership` model are triggered.

However, when I make the same call with `membership_params` that result in the removal of a membership, the membership is removed but the `after_destroy` callbacks are not triggered.

How can I get `Membership` callbacks to trigger on both create and destroy?

```
class User
  has_many :memberships, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships, allow_destroy: true
end

class Memberships
  belongs_to :user
  after_create :do_the_thing
  after_destroy :undo_the_thing # This isn't getting called on destroy
end
```

Comment: Your code works for me as is. Any chance the membership is not being destroyed, only disassociated? Can you post an example of membership_params?